# Http error 500 while uploading with plupload

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7, plupload

I'm getting Http error 500 while uploading with `plupload`, I've searched more about this problem, somebody said it is about memory limit or max upload size or others, I've tested all of them, but the problem is when I'm uploading some files, they are uploading well, but after a while I'm deleting that files and trying to upload again, it causes HTTP error 500.
I'm using `plupload` laravel.

Is there any help?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: You should check your logs (either in `storage/logs` or the webserver's logs) for the details of the error. A 500 error can be many things, but it always comes with a useful message somewhere in your logs.

Comment: Thank you for you response, it is only saying :`The file "animation.mp4" was only partially uploaded`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way with making file part to part `plupload`, Pluplpoad has an ability to using chunk files, I set that and it helped me.

Comment: Care to share the answer? :-)

Comment: Would be great to explain how you fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I found I got HTTP 500 errors when the Plupload chunk size of a file was greater than the configured IIS default upload size.

By [amending this in the `web.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded/3853785#3853785) I was able to prevent the error, e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where `1048576` is in kB, so 1GB in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible issue for 500 errors is when the route cannot be found or has missing or invalid parameters for the server side POST when sending the file.

To diagnose, add the following to the JavaScript, then check the result of `err.response` for clues:

```
var uploader = new window.plupload.Uploader({
    ... 
});

uploader.bind('Error', function (up, err) {
    console.log("Failed to upload file: " + err.response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)